# Supporting persistent user-defined view in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development and was just wondering how I might allow a user to create a button on the main activity as a sort of hotkey and have that button remain there when the app is opened again.

I can imagine that leveraging the settings API would be one way of doing this, although this is not strictly an application option. Alternatively, we could rely on a file for this hotkey configuration.

What is the conventional way of implementing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend  looking into SharedPreferences. 
They allow you to save Key-Value sets to a users device that can be retrieved on future launches, the only restrictions being that the key must be a string and the value must be a primitive data type.

In your case you could for instance save an entry with the button title as the key and a string or int referring to what the button must do, for each button the user creates. And then when the app launches you can use the getAll() method to get a Map of all the previously saved buttons that you can iterate through.

See the android docs for more info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref